# Sum items from different sheets Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have 2 different worksheets like these

[image: Worksheet 1]

[image: Worksheet 2]

I need to have a new summary sheet with the Time spent sum.
Here should be the output:

[image: Worksheet 3]

What is the best way to implement the formula?

Answer (score 3):

I've simulated your situation, creating two tables, one in sheet1, one in sheet2, containing information in cells `B3:C5`, and I came up with this formula:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(B3;Sheet1!$B$3:$C$5;2);VLOOKUP(B3;Sheet2!$B$3:$C$5;2))
```

You might get this to work in your situation by creating an extra column, where you concatenate first name and last name (in order to get the `VLookup()` to work), but I sincerely think there should be easier ways to get this done.

For your information, my table looks as follows:

```
    A     B       C
1
2      Name  Number
3         a       X
4         b       Y
5         c       Z
```

The mentioned formula gave the sum of the `X`s, `Y`s and `Z`s.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can have a univoque ID for the element as you said with concatenating the Name and Surname. I could have some difficulties in copying all the informations (age)  in the third sheet. I need to have the same format of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say i have two sheets:

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2:

[image]

In my opinion the easiest way is:

1. Select the cell you want to paste the results
2. Go to Data - Data Tools - Consolidate
3. Press the arrow at **Reference:** select the first range, press enter and press **Add**. Do the same for the second range.
4. Select **Left column** and press **OK**

**Structure:**

[image]